# Is Mobile Chrome App ready for production?

Tags: google-chrome-app, mobile-chrome, cordova-chrome-app, chrome-app-developer-tool

When surfing to https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/mobile-chrome-apps there is a big bolded note right on the start which state "The Chrome Apps for Mobile toolchain is in developer preview.", reading that few days ago made me think that the project is not production ready for the time being.

Today someone recommended it and although it seems really good I'm afraid that it's not ready yet, so is it?

Take into account that I'm building a financial app which **must** be secured.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I would say that any project that states it's a *developer preview* can not be considered secure or stable for sensitive financial applications or production environments.

Comment: I agree but I'm a little puzzled in regard to what they mean by toolchain...

Comment: [Toolchain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toolchain)

Comment: Yeah Xan I know what's a toolchain, but how can I know if its in such state only cause their CADT (for example) is in such a state but the rest is OK?
What I need is a formal answer...